# is components version != package version normal when in cmake find_package?

Tags: c++, cmake

my env:

```
cmake version 3.16.3
OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
cpp-httplib v0.7.0
```

my sysroot

```
-rw-r--r--  1 developer developer    41292 Jan 14  2018 libcrypt.a
-rw-r--r--  1 developer developer  3143988 Mar 29  2018 libcrypto.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 developer developer       16 Mar 29  2018 libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 developer developer       18 Mar 29  2018 libcrypto.so.1.0.0 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.2
-rwxrw-r--  1 developer developer  1497376 Mar 29  2018 libcrypto.so.1.0.2
-rw-r--r--  1 developer developer  1827956 Mar 29  2018 libcrypto.so.1.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 developer developer       46 Mar 29  2018 libcrypt.so -> ../../../lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt.so.1
-rw-r--r--  1 developer developer   269496 Oct  7  2017 libssl3.so
-rw-r--r--  1 developer developer   490932 Mar 29  2018 libssl.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 developer developer       13 Mar 29  2018 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.1
-rwxrw-r--  1 developer developer   320924 Mar 29  2018 libssl.so.1.0.2
-rw-r--r--  1 developer developer   327952 Mar 29  2018 libssl.so.1.1
```

the CMakeLists.txt in cpp-httplib specifics that:

```
set(_HTTPLIB_OPENSSL_MIN_VER "1.1.1")
...
find_package(OpenSSL ${_HTTPLIB_OPENSSL_MIN_VER} COMPONENTS Crypto SSL QUIET)
...
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${_INTERFACE_OR_PUBLIC}
    OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto
)
```

I included [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib) in my project, I built it and checked shared object with [ldd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), then I got

```
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so.1.1 (0x7572c000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.2 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.2 (0x75ac3000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x754c6000)
```

I understand the version isn't matched exactly due to the EXACT option is not set.
but why libssl is linking to 1.1 only and libcrypto is linking to 1.0.2 and 1.1?

Comment: When link with libraries, CMake normally uses non-soversion variant of the library: `libssl.so`, `libcrypto.so`, etc. Probably, you executable is linked with `libcrypto.so.1.0.2` for reasons, not depending from OpenSSL.

Comment: So in linking, ```libcrypto``` and ```libssl``` are two different things, there could be various versions be linked if my executable is trying to?

I know ```libssl``` depends on ```libcrypto```.
Is there any chance that the executable is trying to link ```libssl.so.1.1``` and ```libcrypto.so.1.0.2``` only? if yes, will there be any problems?

Comment: "Is there any chance that the executable is trying to link `libssl.so.1.1` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.2` only? if yes, will there be any problems?" - I wouldn't recommend that. Try to find out why your project is linked with `libcrypto.so.1.0.2` and fix that linkage.